# ListView scrollbar fix for different cell height

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the ListView, then cells have different height.
When you scrolling the list, scrollbar indicator changes its length.

If you set `android:smoothScrollbar` to false value, it's will not. But the scrollbar will be a real antsy.

So, the solution to override `computeVerticalScrollExtent()`(calculates lenght of the scrollbar indicator) and `computeVerticalScrollOffset()`(calculates position of the scrollbar indicator).

The problem is that I do not know where to start. How to get total height of the ListView without measuring every cell? How to get current position, how to calculate that's all?

Maybe you have already encountered this problem. What will advise?

Comment: i have this problem :(